# Multiple years grep

Tags: grep, search, file-search

How can I grep exact years in my file which contains world champions from years 1950-2000 but I want only years 1950/60/70/80/90/00? Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -E "19[5-9]0|2000"
```

`man grep`:

```
   -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular  expression  (ERE,  see
          below).
```

Answer (score 0):

Another two solutions:

1. these years ends with `0`, so you can call it like: `grep "0$"`
2. numbers are divisible by 10: `awk '{ if ($1 % 10 == 0) {print} }'`

Comment: Your `grep` assumes the year to be at the end of the line and your `awk` for it to be in the first column - this might be too restrictive and is a bit contradictory in itself.

Comment: I'm sure it's good enough for the question above - there are just years specified, nothing more :) To be honest, if the input looks like `1999 some string 1950 yay another string`, than any `grep` is useful there and one have to use `awk` anyway.I believe in people that they think before copy, paste and run :)

Comment: I'm not even blaming you for OP's insufficient input/output samples, yet if someone else stumbles across, it might be misinterpreted as a rather universal answer. And for that last point ... apart from recklessness, someone not familiar with PCRE or even basics of it might not know why things don't work out. It's about the universal approach of the whole Q&A system here.